# PL/SQL Before-After-Pattern

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to use a before-after-pattern approach with PL/SQL (PSEUDO CODE):

Pattern method:

```
procedure doIt(DO_SOMETHING)
is
  l_cnt                     pls_integer := 1;
begin
   loop
      begin
        DO_SOMETHING;
        exit;

      exception
        when exception changed then
          if l_cnt = 2 then
            --raise exception...
          else
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
          end if;
       end;
    end loop;
end;
```

And execute it like this:

```
begin
  doIt(execute immediate sql_statement using in or out);
end;
```

As you can see, I would like to use different dynamic sql statements (execute immediate with one or more in and out variables) but always the same before-after-pattern approach.

Have someone an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the before/after pattern. What's with the loop and the counter?

Comment: So u want the user to execute what in DO_SOMETHING?  If selecting, they'll need a returned cursor, if any DML/DDL or anything open ended, this is a very scary approach imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not so nice, but it works. Perhaps you can start from it and make something better:
I used 2 parameters in the doIt function-
1) the command to execute immediate
2) the arguments as an anydata type
In the execute immediate command I've put all the logic from translating the anydata to some type which I created to wrap the IN OUT parameters.

here is the code:

a type like this should be created for every different command:

```
create or replace type some_type as object(a number, b number);
/
```

this is the procedure :

```
create or replace procedure doIt(aa in varchar2, param IN OUT anydata) is
begin
  execute immediate aa using in out param;
end doIt;
/
```

and this is how I call it (in this example I just selected count(*) from dual into some OUT param):

```
declare
  i number;
  prm some_type;
  ad anydata;
  a number;
  b number;
begin

  prm := new some_type(a,b);
  ad := anydata.convertobject(prm);

  doIt('declare prmAd anydata := :0; prm1 some_type; x number; begin x := prmAd.getobject(prm1); select count(*) into prm1.a from dual; :0 := anydata.convertobject(prm1); end;', ad);

  i := ad.GetObject(prm);
  dbms_output.put_line(prm.a);
end;
```

basically you can add to the doIt procedure what ever you want, and run with it any command.

I guess you can make things nices- move some of the execute immediate string to the doIt procedure, maybe declare the type better and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find much information on Before/After pattern but looking at what your trying to achieve it could look something like this:

```
create or replace
procedure doIt(stmt in varchar2, param in varchar2)
is
  l_cnt pls_integer := 1;
begin
   loop
      begin
        execute immediate stmt using param;
        exit;

      exception
        when others then
          if l_cnt = 2 then
            raise;
          else
            l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
          end if;
       end;
    end loop;
end;  
/

-- run it 
exec doIt('insert into my_table (col1) values ( :val1 )', 'richard' );
```

The problem here is that if you want to pass two parameters then you will have to override 'doIt' eg:

```
procedure doIt(stmt in varchar2, param1 in varchar2, param2 in varchar2)
... 
using param1, param2
```

Also the other caveat is passing different data types into param.  Again you could override the procedure with the correct data type - be warned this could get messy with multiple data types or number of arguments.